# Regex to match sloppy fractions / mixed numbers

Tags: regex

I have a series of text that contains mixed numbers (ie: a whole part and a fractional part). The problem is that the text is full of human-coded sloppiness:

1. The whole part may or may not exist (ex: "10")
2. The fractional part may or may not exist (ex: "1/3")
3. The two parts may be separated by spaces and/or a hyphens (ex: "10 1/3", "10-1/3", "10 - 1/3").
4. The fraction itself may or may not have spaces between the number and the slash (ex: "1 /3", "1/ 3", "1 / 3").
5. There may be other text after the fraction that needs to be ignored

I need a regex that can parse these elements so that I can create a proper number out of this mess.

Comment: I've already got a solution regex, and it works really well, so I'm going to share it with SO in the hopes that it will save someone else a lot of work.

Comment: Which language and/or regex engine is it for?

Comment: It was for Java, but with RegexBuddy I could have easily flipped it to any number of engines.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's a regex that will handle all of the data I can throw at it:

```
(\d++(?! */))? *-? *(?:(\d+) */ *(\d+))?.*$
```

This will put the digits into the following groups:

1. The whole part of the mixed number, if it exists
2. The numerator, if a fraction exits
3. The denominator, if a fraction exists

Also, here's the RegexBuddy explanation for the elements (which helped me immensely when constructing it):

```
Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «(\d++(?! */))?»
   Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «?»
   Match a single digit 0..9 «\d++»
      Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, without giving back (possessive) «++»
   Assert that it is impossible to match the regex below starting at this position (negative lookahead) «(?! */)»
      Match the character “ ” literally « *»
         Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «*»
      Match the character “/” literally «/»
Match the character “ ” literally « *»
   Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «*»
Match the character “-” literally «-?»
   Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «?»
Match the character “ ” literally « *»
   Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «*»
Match the regular expression below «(?:(\d+) */ *(\d+))?»
   Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «?»
   Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 2 «(\d+)»
      Match a single digit 0..9 «\d+»
         Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
   Match the character “ ” literally « *»
      Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «*»
   Match the character “/” literally «/»
   Match the character “ ” literally « *»
      Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «*»
   Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 3 «(\d+)»
      Match a single digit 0..9 «\d+»
         Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
Match any single character that is not a line break character «.*»
   Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «*»
Assert position at the end of the string (or before the line break at the end of the string, if any) «$»
```

Comment: the `.*$` part is pointless, it just throws away what it matches. Just remove it. Other than that, it doesn't look too bad.

Comment: I was looking for a similar solution and this is the one that ended up working well for me: http://regexlib.com/REDetails.aspx?regexp_id=2127

Answer (score 2):

I think it may be easier to tackle the different cases (full mixed, fraction only, number only) separately from each other.  For example:

```
sub parse_mixed {
  my($mixed) = @_;

  if($mixed =~ /^ *(\d+)[- ]+(\d+) *\/ *(\d)+(\D.*)?$/) {
    return $1+$2/$3;
  } elsif($mixed =~ /^ *(\d+) *\/ *(\d+)(\D.*)?$/) {
    return $1/$2;
  } elsif($mixed =~ /^ *(\d+)(\D.*)?$/) {
    return $1;
  }
}

print parse_mixed("10"), "\n";
print parse_mixed("1/3"), "\n";
print parse_mixed("1 / 3"), "\n";
print parse_mixed("10 1/3"), "\n";
print parse_mixed("10-1/3"), "\n";
print parse_mixed("10 - 1/3"), "\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `Perl 5.10`, this is how I would write it.

```
m{
  ^
  \s*       # skip leading spaces

  (?'whole'
   \d++
   (?! \s*[\/] )   # there should not be a slash immediately following a whole number
  )

  \s*

  (?:    # the rest should fail or succeed as a group

    -?        # ignore possible neg sign
    \s*

    (?'numerator'
     \d+
    )

    \s*
    [\/]
    \s*

    (?'denominator'
     \d+
    )
  )?
}x
```

Then you can access the values from the `%+` variable like this:

```
$+{whole};
$+{numerator};
$+{denominator};
```